# Treeview clicking anywhere on the root node should expand the child node

Tags: c#, wpf

I used TreeViewItem_Selected method for tree-view root node expansion in combo box.
It is expanding fine but how to collapse it? and i want to open my combo box when the parent node is selected and it should close when child node is selected.And whenever we are trying to expand and collapse the tree view continuously it is not working fine. Is there any alternative for TreeViewItem_Selected property? can i implement this expanded property directly for a combo box?

Comment: would you please share some code?

Comment: I used the following method for treeview root node expansion:           private void TreeViewItem_Selected(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   TreeViewItem tvi = (TreeViewItem)e.OriginalSource;
   if (tvi != null)
      tvi.IsExpanded = !tvi.IsExpanded;
}

Comment: I used the following method for treeview root node expansion:           private void TreeViewItem_Selected(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   TreeViewItem tvi = (TreeViewItem)e.OriginalSource;
   if (tvi != null)
      tvi.IsExpanded = !tvi.IsExpanded;
}   
and to keep combo box as open when clicks on the root node i used the following code:                                                   
  this.reasonCodesCb.IsDropDownOpen = true;
              

                }